# How to pass COM array to managed code?

Tags: .net, c++, vb.net, com, interop

I have a .Net application (VB in particular, although I would this to be as language agnostic as possible) that uses a COM object (made in C++).

I need to implement a event in COM that passes a char array from C++ to .Net. I guess I need to convert the array to a managed array; 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
Private Sub ComEventHandler(ByVal dataPtr As Integer, ByVal size As Integer) Handles myComObject.OnEvent
    Dim managedData(0 To size - 1) As Byte
    Dim data As IntPtr = dataPtr

    If (size = 0) Then
        Marshal.Copy(data, managedData, 0, size)
        ...
    End If
    ...
End Sub
```

The COM event passes the char array as it is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the framework used. Basically, it will come down to MFC or ATL; With later versions of MFC you can mix and match, so I recommand Atl.

Have a look at [Atl's CComSafeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xzbsee8%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class template for this purpose. You'll want

However, do consider using `_bstr_t` to wrap strings if this is really text (making it easy to do the encoding conversions RIGHT without much effort). [1]

---

[1] There is `CComBstr` too these days, but I've personally used _bstr_t since way back and had great experience due to the conversions to/from BSTR e.g.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Isn't there a way to just pass the pointer to the data to .Net and convert it to a managed array? I'm not very fond of Safe arrays (although I didn't know of CComSafeArary). It's not text and it's a lot of data (video) so I want to avoid as much overhead as possible.

Comment: You can if you use STL vectors; IIRC there are ATL adapters that work with them (but it's been a long time)

Comment: Thank you very much, sehe. I will take a look at this ASAP!